# drupal 8 modifying the menu items path

Tags: 8, navigation, group

I work on an drupal 8 application that use the `group` module with the restriction of only one group per user. i want to be able to modify the menu items so that the id of the user's group is always in the url. this way i can use `views` with a group id in the url.

I search and i always go to the same pages with the same example that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

this will not work because the menu are build during the cache clearing, thus the url cannot be dynamic.

i instead use an EventSubscriber on Kernel::REQUEST and redirect the user if need be.

Comment: this did't work either i made a custom block to handle the menus